# Variable in Custom Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a Google Sheets cell value to a custom menu item.  I have the menu building via an onOpen() function.  I can create a normal text VAR and add it to the menu item and it works.  But when I try to create VARs above `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` with, for example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");  
var mycellvalue = ss.getSheetByName("A1").setValue;

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem(mycellvalue + 'Some Text', 'fuction1')
    .addToUi();`
```

That doesn't work, and the custom menu disappears.

So, how do I create a VAR with a cell value and then use it in a `.addItem` line?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to first use getRange() to access the cell then use getValue() to store the its value. You can try this code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mycellvalue = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getRange("A1").getValue(); //feel free to change the sheet name and cell as needed

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem(mycellvalue + 'Some Text', 'fuction1')
    .addToUi();
}
```

### References

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding#getrange)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: That worked perfectly Duueyn, very much appreciated!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)